# Device that can push out independent pin points?

Tags: 3d-printing

I'm looking for a device that can push out independent pinpoints from something similar to a Pin Point Impression Toy. I'm looking to create a 3D image from for example my computer. Does anybody know the name of such a device or can point me in the right direction of making one?

I've been looking now for a while, but I'm having some slight problems finding a good way to describe it as a search term.

I'm sorry if this is the wrong forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any devices that exist for this purpose (besides devices that are not for sale, such as [the MIT Media Lab's "Transform" table](http://tangible.media.mit.edu/project/transform/)), but I'd imagine that the 2 most promising approaches for a homemade solution would be:

1. Use a robot arm or X/Y table to move to each pin location and push it the desired distance -- one pin at a time.  Reset the pins by just tilting the pins' frame back.
2. Attach a [bowden cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowden_cable) to each pin and use a servo (or linear actuator) at the other end to control the position.  This has the advantage of setting all the pins in parallel.